# correct way of dereferencing a macrovariable

Tags: sas

I want to initialize 20 macrovariables with the row numbers of 20 datasets. Finally I want to create 20 arrays(test1-test20)  initialized to the sizes obtained from the 20 datasets. But I have problems of dereferencing the variables that keep the size of the length Iam a bit unsure if it is correct dereference as:

> &&&var&I.._rows

could i get some advice? the code snippet is below

```
%let var1 = dataset112;
%let var2 = dataset22212;
%let var3 =  dataset3222;
...
%let var20  =dataset213321;
%let varN =20;
%macro setsize;
%do i=1 %to &varN;
proc sql noprint;
     select count(surv_probs)
     into : &&var&i.._rows
     from work.&&var&i; 
quit;
%end;
%mend;


%macro al;
%do I=1 %to &varN;
array test&I {&&&var&I.._rows};
%end;
%mend;

data ttt;
%al
run;
```

Comment: Tip: You could always test resolve a macro variable with `%put`. And passing it to `%symdel` deletes it from the symbol table. Note that SAS stores it in uppercase, so you'll have to use `%upcase` with the macro variable.

Answer (score 0):

Before you start writing macros make sure you know what code you want to write. So let's make some macro variables and see if the references you are using in your SQL query are right.

```
%let var1 = dataset112;
%let var2 = dataset22212;
%let i=1 ;

%put Target varname = &&var&i.._rows ;
%put Source dataset name= &&var&i;
```

So let's set that macro variable to some value and try to display it.

```
%let dataset112_rows=123 ;
%put Number of rows = &&&&&&var&i.._rows ;
```

On the first pass `&i.` is replaced and all of the `&&` are converted to `&` so you get `&&&var1._rows`.  After the second pass you will have `&dataset112_rows`. So after the third pass you will get the result `123`.

If you explain your real over all problem there is probably a way to do what you want without tying yourself into macro variable reference knots.